# How to Consume OData or Web Services from Office 365 on Windows Phone?

Tags: claims-based-auth, office-365

I am struggling to consume a web service of Office 365 like `_vti_bin/lists.asmx`.

I found good documentation and an example of how to work with SharePoint and Forms Based Authentication in the SharePoint and Windows Phone 7 Training Kit, but it seems that Office 365 is using Claims Based Authentication / Windows LiveID.

Does anyone have a working example / concept for Windows Phone?

Comment: Have you tried to access the service through REST/OData protocol?

Comment: Nice, question! We need more OData questions on this site!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the credentials on the web service like this:

```
// -- Windows LiveID Client SDK --
using Microsoft.WindowsLive.Id.Client;

...

private void FunctionWorkingWithListsService()
{
    IdentityManager identityManager;
    WindowsLiveAuthenticationModule authModule;

    Lists listsWebService = new Lists();
    listsWebService.Url = listServiceUrl;

    listsWebService.UserAgent = listsWebService.UserAgent + ";" + 
      WindowsLiveAuthenticationModule.WindowsLiveClientHeader;
    listsWebService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential();

    // -- DO WORK --
}
```

This is not an answer specific to Windows Phone, but answers the more general question of how to authenticate to a web service using Windows LiveID.

Just make sure the user account has the correct level of permissions on the list to perform whatever actions you are trying to perform.

Microsoft has a full code sample of connecting to an Office Live web service using Windows LiveID [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862331%28v=office.12%29.aspx). That's where I pulled the basis of this code from.